# odoo 8 update field other table

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I want to update a field named cost_price_set in model sale.order.line with 40 as a sample. I have try this but the value still does not updated in the field.

```
@api.depends('line_ids.sale_order_id','line_ids.product_id')
def hpp_update(self):
    for record in self:
        invoice_pool = self.env['sale.order.line']
        for invoice in invoice_pool.search([('order_id', '=', record.line_ids.sale_order_id.id),('product_id', '=', record.line_ids.product_id.id)]):
            invoice.write({'cost_price_set': '40'})
    return True
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: I think it's because you need to make sure that the method it's called. For that I will need more details of what you wanna do and what have you done in your module

Answer (score -1):

I found that nothing wrong with the script. The problem was that the field that I want to inset is compute field. When the field is non compute, it works.